# VBScript read digital signature of file

Tags: vbscript, digital-signature

Is there any way to read Digital Signature of file using VBScript? I need to read property: "Name of signer"... I need to check if tested java.exe file is signed by Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way but UAC will affect the output. When script executes under certain situation, output varies.

When `blnShowGUI` is set to `True` and I click Install, the output is "Signed". Otherwise script says not signed.

[image: Verifying C:\Windows\System32\java.exe]

Unless "Always install..." is selected, you will get this prompt every time. Once "Always install..." is Installed, the script returns consistent output.

[image: Install Options]

Credit goes to [ActiveXperts](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/security/#VerifySign.htm) and reference [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t18ks7d8(v=vs.84).aspx)

```
set objSigner = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Signer")
'blnShowGUI = True
blnShowGUI = False
blnIsSigned = objSigner.VerifyFile("C:\Windows\System32\java.exe", blnShowGUI)
If blnIsSigned then
    WScript.Echo "Script has been signed."
Else
   WScript.Echo " Script has not been signed."
End If
```

You may want to modify it so it invokes UAC if first silent try returns "not signed".